# Why does my Keras Conv Net only return 1?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

```
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_h_w,img_h_w,1)))
   model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))
   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01),metrics=['accuracy'])
   model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=3, verbose=1)
   score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

Running this returns

```
2500/2500 [==============================] - 5s 2ms/step - loss: 7.5694 - acc: 0.5252
Epoch 2/3
2500/2500 [==============================] - 5s 2ms/step - loss: 7.5694 - acc: 0.5252
Epoch 3/3
2500/2500 [==============================] - 6s 2ms/step - loss: 7.5694 - acc: 0.5252
```

Which shows the accuracy is at 50%, and when I look at the predictions made, I see it only outputs 1. It is meant to classify images into 0 or 1.

Comment: 2500 is likely not enough data to train a deep learning framework. I would suggest other machine learning approaches.

Answer (score 1):

It is only outputting 1 because `softmax` makes no sense when given a single input. Softmax computed with only one input $x$ is equivalent to $\frac{e^x}{e^x} = 1$.

In other words, the line

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

is wrong. Use `sigmoid` instead:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

or read more about one-hot encoding your expected output and the helper function https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical.

Answer (score 0):

For binary classification you can use `softmax` as the output layer but you should consider that if you do so, your last layer have to have two neurons, each corresponds to one specific class. Moreover, you have to use `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function. Change the following code:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

to:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01),metrics=['accuracy'])
```